# python replace() function is not working as supposed

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop, replace

```
res = "heeellooo"
D = {"aaa":"a","eee":"e","iii":"i","ooo":"o","uuu":"u","yyy":"y"}
for i,j in D.items():
    res.replace(i,j)
print(res)
```

the output expected is:
`hello`
what I got instead is `heeellooo`

any idea why this is happening??

Comment: `replace()` returns a copy of the string. Please read the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop you have to mention that certain content of variable "res" needs to be replaced with the certain content from the variable "D".

So, you have to change that line of code to this:

```
res = res.replace(i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Classical problem:

```
res = "heeellooo"
D = {"aaa":"a","eee":"e","iii":"i","ooo":"o","uuu":"u","yyy":"y"}
for i,j in D.items():
    res=res.replace(i,j)
print(res)
```

Comment: If it's a "classic problem", you should flag it as a duplicate instead of answering it.

Comment: Sorry, I will know the next time.

Answer (score 0):

```py
res = "heeellooo"
D = {"aaa":"a","eee":"e","iii":"i","ooo":"o","uuu":"u","yyy":"y"}
for i,j in D.items():
    res = res.replace(i,j) # use the returned value of `replace()`
print(res)
```